# WebGL / Three.js - Particles colored by texture flicker erratically while moving camera

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vko8hzzs/4/) I put together showing the problem of particles "flickering" while being colored using a texture and while the camera is moving.

Update: There should be no animation or movement happening on the particles. If when you click and drag on the viewport and the particles are flickering or changing colors at all then you are seeing the issue. This is a problem I've tested and seen on both firefox and chrome with mac OS 10.9 and windows 7.

The particles are not overlapping or clipping in any way. If the particles are animated with a regular shader the flickering does not happen. It's only when the particles are colored using a texture (in this case using THREE.WebGLRenderTarget), is the flickering evident. It is done this way in order to capture previous frames and store them in a buffer (that could then be used in more advanced ways not shown in the jsfiddle example).

It actually seems like the fragment shader might be mistakenly grabbing a neighbor pixel, instead of it's target, but I'm not certain - and that doesn't make much sense, because the target coordinates are only generated on init(), and they don't change after that.

The target pixel coordinates for each particle are passed as a vertex attribute to the fragment shader 1-1 unaltered (as a varying but with no varying value).

```
uniform sampler2D colorMap; // The texture being used to color each particle
varying float v_geoX; // x,y coordinates passed as varyings
varying float v_geoY;

void main() {
    // Normally pulling the correct color, but this seems to get confused during camera movement.
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(colorMap, vec2(v_geoX, v_geoY));
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this without the flickering? When I apply this technique to larger and faster animations the problem only seems to get worse. It's happening on all browsers I've checked so far.

Comment: I'm not seeing any flickering. Is the color animation necessary in this demo? Is a render target necessary to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Also no flickering here, Chrome and Firefox - Linux. What GPU, browser and OS are you using? Any driver workarounds applied(about:gpu)?

Comment: @WestLangley The render target is necessary as I need to capture the last few frames to use for animations. I simplified the jsfiddle as a baseline example of when the problem seems to occur.

Comment: Yes, I am clicking and dragging. No flickering. Is the animation necessary to show the flickering? If not, turn it off and simplify the demo.

Comment: The animation was helping me but I've simplified it so that the animation is not updating and there should be zero movement. Do you still see no flickering while moving the camera? http://jsfiddle.net/vko8hzzs/4/

Comment: Not seeing any flickering when moving the camera on OS X 10.10 with Chrome 39 or Safari 8.0 -- except on the edges of the canvas as particles enter/leave the frustum.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up WestLangley. I have also seen it working fine on another machine now, as well as heard that from some others that it works too. Looks like it might be a bug that happens on only some versions of browsers. I will get more details on the versions where it happens, as well as perhaps posting a video on youtube of flickering and try filling a bug.

Comment: Tip: if there is more than 1 user commenting, then you must direct your reply to @username, otherwise the user does not get a notification of your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're pointing at the edges between texels.

These lines

```
   geoX.push(tx / imageSize);
   geoY.push(1.0 - ty / imageSize); // flip y
```

compute the exact edge between texels. What I mean by that is lets say `imageSize` is 4 texels and lets say `tx` and `ty` go from `0` to `3`

Your texture coordinates go like this

```
   0    0.25  0.5   0.75       <- texture coords you're computing
   |     |     |     |     
   V     V     V     V     
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+
   |     |     |     |     |
   |     |     |     |     |   <- texels
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

But the texture coords you want are like this

```
     0.125 0.375 0.625 0.875   
      |     |     |     |   
      V     V     V     V  
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+
   |     |     |     |     |
   |     |     |     |     |   <- texels
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

The easiest fix is to add 1/2 a texel

```
   geoX.push(tx / imageSize       + 0.5 / imageSize);
   geoY.push(1.0 - ty / imageSize + 0.5 / imageSize); // flip y
```

The problem is with your math pointing directly between texels rounding errors make it pick one texel or the other. Choosing the center of the texel will fix that. If the image didn't have so much contrast between neighboring texels you might not have noticed.

Comment: That fixes it! Thank you @gman! I suspected it had something to do with grabbing the wrong neighboring pixel (texel)! I was working on a brute force solution, by doubling pixels to give padding space and room for error, but what you have is much better and fixes the problem directly. Btw, here is an updated fiddle for anyone seeing the flickering and wants to test this solution http://jsfiddle.net/vko8hzzs/5/. Also I am pretty sure the flickering is only happening on machines with a NVIDIA GeForce graphics card (doesn't matter which browser).