# Need average and max value of a texture in shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have a RenderTexture and need to calculate its average and maximum pixel value. The RenderTexture is of RFloat format so only has one component. Also it does not use mipmap right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some search it seems the best way to do it is to reduce the texture meaning run a shader that its input is of texture size and output is of half the input size. We can sample 4 neighboring pixels and calculate the max from them and write the value to the output.

```
    sampler2D _MainTex;
    float4 _MainTex_ST;
    float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;

    v2f vert(appdata v)
    {
        v2f o;
        o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
        o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
        return o;
    }
    float4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
    {
        float dx = _MainTex_TexelSize.x*0.5;
        float maximum = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv + float2(-dx,-dx));
        maximum = max(maximum, tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv + float2(dx,-dx)));
        maximum = max(maximum, tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv + float2(-dx,dx)));
        maximum = max(maximum, tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv + float2(dx,dx)));
        return maximum;
    }
```

The next iteration gets the output of the previous iteration and writes to a rendertexture that is half its input meaning quarter the original texture. So the sizes go like 1024,512,256,... and so on up to a 1 by 1 texture and that gives the max. Here is some code to show the CPU side:

```
        private RenderTexture Reduce(RenderTexture diff, Material mat)
    {
        int reductions = POT.GetPowerFromNum(diff.width);
        var rtList = new List<RenderTexture>();
        int smallRes = diff.width/2;
        var bigRT = diff;
        for (int i = 0; i < reductions; i++)
        {
            var smallRT = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(smallRes, smallRes, 0, diff.format);
            rtList.Add(smallRT);
            GpuUtils.Blit(bigRT,smallRT,mat);
            bigRT = smallRT;
            smallRes >>= 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < reductions-1; i++)
        {
            RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(rtList[i]);
        }
        return rtList[reductions-1];
    }
```

Here `diff` is the original render texture, `GetPowerFromNum` calculates the power of two like 10 for 1024, and mat is the material of the shader.

For average one can do the same for an average shader instead of max or simply enable mipmaps for the render texture and read the highest mipmap level.

Comment: I don't know if it's a mistake, or if it's my knowledge that doesn't go far enough, but I changed the type of maximum in the shader to float4...